# Cannot get React JS app to render in IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

I am trying to get a react JS app to render in IE 11 but it is not rendering. I believe I have tried all of the suggestions from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379. This example renders fine in other browsers for me.

Here is my html file

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"> </script>
    <script src="/static/js/test.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/jsx">
            ReactDOM.render( < Test / > ,
            document.getElementById('root')
            );
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is `/static/js/test.jsx`

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( < h1 > This is a test < /h1>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it to work in IE11 is to import Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 so it will work in IE11. Note that script type should be "text/babel" for both the inline script and the script import. Alternatively, you can transpile the javascript in the [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) and replace your code. Here's the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="./Test.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      "use strict";
      ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here's Test.js

```
"use strict";

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added that and I got an error saying it is an illegal export

Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 7: Illegal export declaration
    at /static/js/test.jsx:7:undefined

Comment: I try to make a test with your sample code but it gave me an error in every browser for JSXTransformer.js You can try to run this sample code in IE 11. https://textuploader.com/1ao5j

Comment: @aplassard, my apologies. "export" is part of ES6 so it won't work in IE11. As well,  "class" and other ES6 syntax won't work. As Deepak-MSFT showed in his example, include Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5 so it will work in IE11. You will also have to use type="text/babel" for your scripts. I was able to get it to work and will update my code.